# Prevent Javascript ChildNodes from Parsing &lt; and &gt;

Tags: javascript, child-nodes

I discovered today, that if I do this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<div>&lt; x</div>";
var node = div.firstElementChild;
var childNodes = node.childNodes;
console.log(childNodes[0].data);
```

the output is `< x`. But I'd like my `&lt;` unchanged, since changing it to `<` messes up the parser I wrote.

What's the recommended way of **not** changing `&lt;` to `<`? One thing I could come up with was replacing `&lt;` with `&amp;lt;`, which yields:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<div>&amp;lt; x</div>";
var node = div.firstElementChild;
var childNodes = node.childNodes;
console.log(childNodes[0].data);
```

with the output being `&lt; x`. Is there a better way? Because in this case I'd preprocess my entire document with a regex replacing `&lt;` with `&amp;lt` and `&gt;` with `&amp;gt;`. But this seems quite hacky and who knows if there aren't more properties that were escaped and are now changed by the `childNodes` method?

**Update / Clarification:**

I receive a **html string** as an input into my parser. This could for example be
`<div> The <br> World <span> is &lt; Space </span> </div>`. I then want to write a parser for this html. I first create a HTMLElement using `document.createElement('div');`. From there I walk the dom and do my postprocessing. I specifically want to find all "adjacent-sibling-text-or-br-nodes". That's why I iterated over the nodes with `childNodes`, because opposed to `children` it also returns the text nodes.

Comment: How does that mess up your parser? Sounds like it’s the one doing something wrong. Unless `&lt;` is supposed to be treated as text…? This might need some context.

Comment: It is not `childNodes` that changes it. It is the `innerHTML` property that *interprets* HTML. `&lt;` is the HTML way of denoting `<`. So you'll have to do it like you did and write ampersand in the HTML way: `&amp;`.

Comment: You could split the HTML tag part from the text content, and just add an empty --- created --- `div` element, and then set its `textContent` property to `'&lt; x'`.

Comment: @Ryan yes it's meant as text, that's why it was escaped. The wysiwyg escapes the user input `<` to `&lt;`. But then in my processor it becomes unescaped again due to parsing it with `childNodes`.

Comment: @trincot +1 Always safer to set text instead of html, anyway.

Comment: @bersling: So `&lt;` is *not* meant as text; `<` is meant as text. Important distinction. Whatever processing you have on top of this should keep text nodes in the form of text – maybe by escaping them on output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if that string is to represent the text as you see it, then it is *not* valid HTML. In HTML, a literal ampersand is not written as `&`, but as `&amp;`. `&` has a special meaning in correct HTML: it is used as part of HTML entity names.

A solution is to handle the text separate from the HTML tags: add the element first, and then set its text content:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.textContent = '&lt; x';
div.appendChild(node);
var childNodes = node.childNodes;
console.log(childNodes[0].data);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a html string to start with. So for example my wysiwyg returns `<div>&lt; x</div>`, then I have to start my postprocessing with this.

Comment: The problem with that is that according to your expectations, that is *not* a valid HTML string, since you expect the `&` to be taken literally, while HTML defines `&` as a special character for us in HTML entity names. If your wysiwyg's documentation states that it returns HTML, then it is buggy. ;-)

Comment: What will your wysiwyg return when it wants to denote a literal `<` inside the `div` tag? If the answer is `<`, then it becomes even more clear it is not valid HTML, if the answer is `&lt;` then how is it different from what you have now?

Comment: The wysiwyg returns `&lt;` when you enter `<`. How do you mean, different from what I have now? I get `&lt;` but then inside of my postprocessor by iterating with `childNodes` the `&lt;` is converted to `<` again. You can test the output of the wysiwyg at https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor by entering "code view".

Comment: But then the HTML returned by the wysiwyg is correct. Then the problem is that you want to interpret the HTML as such, but not when it has `&lt;`. Then "suddenly" you want to see it as literal `&lt;`. This is not consistent, because then you should *also* take `<div>` literally, which you don't: that you *do* interpret as HTML. So, there is no other way then to find the logic in what you try to do, and split the part you want to interpret as HTML away from the part that you don't want to interpret as HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! My mistake was to assume that if e.g. `<span> bla </span>` was a child, then `childNode.data` would also be `<span> bla <br> </span>` but the `.data` is not even present in this case. So in the `.data` is the *interpreted* data of the textnodes, correct?

Comment: Yes, the data is what will be displayed. It is not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you use innerHTML it seems to work..

Does this work for you?

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<div>&lt; x</div>";
var node = div.firstElementChild;
console.log(node.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as I need to iterate over the childNodes in my postprocessing.

Comment: So why not iterate over each child node and access the innerHTML property?

Comment: The iteration is what I'm trying to do with `childNodes`. What else would you suggest? Note: It's important that I can also process text nodes, that's why I chose `childNodes`